# In R: Selecting and replacing a sequence into a new column

Tags: r

I have a .csv that looks at waste generation in the US, loaded in R Studio. I am creating a path for waste shipments from shipper to receiver. I tried visualizing the data below to give a sense of what I need. But to describe it, I would like to create a new column called "Path" that takes the second value of data$Receiver state, and lays it below the first value of data$Shipper state. Then I would like this to repeat for every series of two rows.

So far, I have tried selecting a even sequence of data$shipper, and an odd sequence of data$receiver, but i do not know how to overlay them into data$path.

Currently, my data looks like this

```
Shipper | Receiver 
----------------------
Kansas  | Wyoming

Kansas  | Wyoming

Texas   | Vermont

Texas   | Vermont

Idaho   | Ohio

Idaho   | Ohio
```

and I would like to look like this:

```
Shipper | Receiver | Path
----------------------------
Kansas  | Wyoming | Kansas

Kansas  | Wyoming | Wyoming

Texas   | Vermont | Texas

Texas   | Vermont | Vermont

Idaho   | Ohio    | Idaho

Idaho   | Ohio    | Ohio
```

Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

I am sure there are other simpler ways to do this. But I like to use basic loops. Please see if below code works for you:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  if(i %% 2 == 0) {
    data$Path[i] <- as.character(data$Receiver[i])
  } else {
    data$Path[i] <- as.character(data$Shipper[i])
  }
}
```